# Create project folder from netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, directory, project

Please I am using netbeans for java applications, and I have a project open in netbeans and I just want to know how to save it as a folder somewhere in the computer. I mean be able to save the whole project in a folder ( including src, build folders) as in the folders that are created automatically when you create a new project.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an **Export** menu item:

> File -> Export Project -> To Zip...

The zip will contain all your directory's structure.

Comment: I tried it but it's not working, how should I do it exactly ?

Comment: Thing is that when I do export I don't get the "move items" he gets in the video

Comment: But are you able to export the zip, then open it? What does it contain? What if you unzip it in another folder?

Comment: It's working now, it goes into a temp folder, then when I open it I find "build" "nbproject" and "src" folders" thanks. I have another question, if that project was sent to us by someone else, and I opened it in netbeans and modified it and then exported it. If I send it to someone else, is there any way he can know it wasnt done by me? ( I changed the @author  name)